# Is there a way to fill in form values with a button click or post request without submitting the form?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, form-for

I am attempting to fill in a password field of a form with a click (onClick="autoFill());) as shown in the code below.

The click is working without error, but nothing goes into the password field.

I have tried using a different type of form () with document.getElementsByClassName("input-wrapper") and get the same results.

P.S. This is an incremental step towards a goal. The final goal is to be able to fill in the password field with a user controlled JS plugin.

```
<% provide(:title, "Log in") %>
<div  class="center jumbotron">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
 <%= form_for(:session, url: login_path) do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control'  %>

  <%= f.submit "Log in", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %> 

    <a href="#" onClick="autoFill(); return true;" >Click to 
Autofill</a>

     <script type="text/javascript">
function autoFill() {
document.getElementsByClassName("form-control").password_field = 
"My Text Input";
  }
</script>

</div>

</div>
```

I expect the password field to fill with "My Text Input", but nothing is happening to the password field and the url gains an # on click.

Comment: did the link click event happening while you click on the link?

Comment: Yes I tested it with a simple text block and editor like this and it worked: <input type="text" id="input1">  and document.getElementById("input1").value = "My Text Input";

Comment: give that password field a id and try out calling with that id.

Comment: Do you know how to accomplish that with a form_for? @AbhishekAravindan

Comment: `<%= f.password_field :password, :class=> 'form-control', :id=>"some_id"  %>`

Comment: Tried it out. Still getting status 200's but no fill.

Comment: Which, @AbhishekAravindan, wouldn't this mean that it's the password type block that is the problem? I think maybe the document.getElementsByClassName("form-control").password_field = 
"My Text Input"; isn't the right approach for changing the field of a password block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using jQuery?
I've tweaked your code a little

```
<% provide(:title, "Log in") %>
<div class="center jumbotron">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <%= form_for(:session) do |f| %>

        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.email_field :email, id: 'my-email-field-id', class: 'form-control' %>

        <%= f.label :password %>
        <%= f.password_field :password, id: 'my-password-id', class: 'form-control'  %>

        <%= f.submit "Log in", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <%= button_tag 'Click to Autofill', id: 'auto-fill-link' %>
</div>

<script>
  $(function(){
    autoFill();

    function autoFill() {
      $('#auto-fill-link').click(function(){
        $('#my-password-id').val('My Password Input');
        $('#my-email-field-id').val('My Email Input')
      });

    }
  })
</script>
```

Ensure you have `gem 'jquery-rails’` in your gemfile. 
Then run `bundle`
Ensure your application.js file includes `//= require jquery` and
`//= require jquery_ujs`

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Restart your server

You may want to place the JS in the script tags into actual .js files elsewhere for tidiness

Comment: Thanks, @yamadaj2 . This workaround works. It appears that my main problem was: var $ = document.getElementById; does not work in Firefox or Google Chrome. Using $ for jquery worked. I'm not aware of any additional security implications regarding the use of this. If anybody is, please speak up. Thanks!